# sam build --use-container failed mounting directory

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, build, aws-sam

There was no issue in building the project a little while back, but it started throwing below error.

> RuntimeError: Container does not exist. Cannot get logs for this
> container

Normally this happens when docker cannot mount the shared directory, but in this case even adding the lambda directory manually in the docker interface didn't help!

**Complete debug log of `sam build --use-container`**

```
Building function 'SAListManagerUrlLambda'

Fetching lambci/lambda:build-python3.7 Docker container image......
Mounting C:\Users\xxxx\xxxx\xxxx\xxxx\functions\xxxx-xxxx\xxxx-xxxx as /tmp/samcli/source:ro,delegated inside runtime container
Container was not created. Skipping deletion
Sending Telemetry: {'metrics': [{'commandRun': {'awsProfileProvided': False, 'debugFlagProvided': True, 'region': '', 'commandName': 'sam build', 'duration': 1292, 'exitReason': 'RuntimeError', 'exitCode': 255, 'requestId': 'cbfcd29c-16ae-xxxx-xxxx-b9ffec8de75a', 'installationId': 'fece8ccc-cb84-xxxx-xxxx-ac72820ef0c3', 'sessionId': 'e1cbc287-1850-xxxx-xxxx-3a235769f7fb', 'executionEnvironment': 'CLI', 'pyversion': '3.7.6', 'samcliVersion': '0.53.0'}}]}
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='aws-serverless-tools-telemetry.us-west-2.amazonaws.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=0.1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\obj\windows-release\37amd64_Release\msi_python\zip_amd64\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
  File "D:\obj\windows-release\37amd64_Release\msi_python\zip_amd64\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
  File "C:\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\__main__.py", line 12, in <module>
    cli(prog_name="sam")
  File "C:\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 829, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 782, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1259, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "C:\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "C:\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\click\decorators.py", line 73, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\lib\telemetry\metrics.py", line 96, in wrapped
    raise exception  # pylint: disable=raising-bad-type
  File "C:\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\lib\telemetry\metrics.py", line 62, in wrapped
    return_value = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\commands\build\command.py", line 129, in cli
    mode,
  File "C:\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\commands\build\command.py", line 194, in do_cli
    artifacts = builder.build()
  File "C:\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\lib\build\app_builder.py", line 117, in build
    function.metadata)
  File "C:\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\lib\build\app_builder.py", line 271, in _build_function
    options)
  File "C:\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\lib\build\app_builder.py", line 369, in _build_function_on_container
    container.wait_for_logs(stdout=stdout_stream, stderr=stderr_stream)
  File "C:\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\local\docker\container.py", line 197, in wait_for_logs
    raise RuntimeError("Container does not exist. Cannot get logs for this container")
RuntimeError: Container does not exist. Cannot get logs for this container
```

Comment: see this, https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sam-cli/issues/837#issuecomment-453375032

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case the reason was different, `Action Center's` `Focus Assist` was set to `Alarms Only`.
This caused the share directory notification to fail, causing the build failure.

So, make sure your `Focus Assist` is set to OFF.
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that many situations can trigger the same error. For more information the --debug option can be used like this:

```
sam build --use-container --debug
```

I see that you are using it, because you got extra information like this:

```
Sending Telemetry: {'metrics': [{'commandRun': {'awsProfileProvided': False, 'debugFlagProvided': True, 'region': '', 'commandName': 'sam build', 'duration': 1292, 'exitReason': 'RuntimeError', 'exitCode': 255, 'requestId': 'cbfcd29c-16ae-xxxx-xxxx-b9ffec8de75a', 'installationId': 'fece8ccc-cb84-xxxx-xxxx-ac72820ef0c3', 'sessionId': 'e1cbc287-1850-xxxx-xxxx-3a235769f7fb', 'executionEnvironment': 'CLI', 'pyversion': '3.7.6', 'samcliVersion': '0.53.0'}}]}

HTTPSConnectionPool(host='aws-serverless-tools-telemetry.us-west-2.amazonaws.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=0.1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

In my case I did suppose that the error was *sending the telemetry*.

My guess is that somehow the build process need pass the region. In my case it is not **us-west-2**.

Anyway, I disabled it as [specified](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-telemetry.html) in the documentation and it now works.

Answer (score 0):

In my case local disk in my cloud9 was almost full, so I had to delete some docker images that comes pre-installed with cloud9.

To remove an image use

```
docker rmi Image
```

This will clear up space and your build will not fail the next time.